# How to setup Eclipse for gvSIG?

Tags: gvsig

I was working on setting development workspace for GvSIG. I referred to https://confluence.prodevelop.es/display/WSS/GvSIG+Installation.

While compiling a simple program it says "extension directory is empty".
In that tutorial it does not explain how to add extensions in extension directory.

Is their any good tutorial on how to setup development environment for GvSIG
or does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 2):

That manual is really old and outdated.

If you want to set up a gvSIG 1.x workspace you can check [this](http://www.gvsig.org/web/docdev/building-from-svn/building-gvsig-from-svn/view?set_language=en). It's not updated for 1.12 but more or less the process is OK.

If you want to develop with gvSIG 2.0 then you have two situations, it's not the same to develop a gvSIG plugin than working with the core. For the first case you don't need to set up a complete workspace with all the gvSIG components.

The entry point for gvSIG 2.0 dev docs is the [quick start guide](http://www.gvsig.org/web/projects/gvsig-desktop/docs/devel/developers_quick_start/2-0.0/introduction). As gvSIG 2.0 is in stabilization process the documents can have some minor errors so the best you can do anyway is post your questions at the gvSIG devel [mailing list](http://joinup.ec.europa.eu/mailman/listinfo/gvsig-desktop-devel) where my colleagues for sure will help you on any glitch.

Good luck!!